# How to underline with space from text different length active item?

Tags: css, elementor

Here is the drill: I have a main menu with items having different length text. I would like to underline the active item (text only), but lower than regular text underline. After digging internet I have come up with this:

```
.current-menu-item:after {
    content: ""; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 80%; 
    padding-top: 2px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff; 
}
```

Problem is - since text is of different length, width 80% does not work well for all. Atm I have gone around creating different menus (lame)... Is there a way to style each item differently when active under one code (thus one menu)? (like have a list under .current-menu-item with instructions for .menu-item-xxx1, instructions for .menu-item-xxx2, etc...?)

Or I am wondering in a wild and there is other more simple solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:nth-child()` to set the width:

```
.current-menu-item:after {
   content: ""; 
   display: block; 
   margin: 0 auto;  
   padding-top: 2px; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff; 
}

.current-menu-item:nth-child(1):after {
  width: 80%;
}

.current-menu-item:nth-child(2):after {
  width: 90%;
}
```

**Note:** Keep in mind it will not work on the inner child if there is only one. For example: If you use `a` elements inside `li` elements for your menu. Then you need to apply `li:nth-child() a:after` and not `li a:nth-child():after`.

Comment: THAT DOES IT!!! Wooping at my desk right now. Thanks a million @TVBZ !!

Comment: My pleasure. If it works, please mark my answer as solution. :)